# PayPal Assisted Account Creation invalid client_id or redirect_uri

Tags: paypal

I followed this [doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/features/set-up-assisted-account-creation/) to Set up Assisted paypal Accounts.

And create sample page with sandbox client id and merchant id as follows.

[image]

When clicked rendered button I get following error page. I checked popup url and found redirect
redirect_uri=https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/conex/ac/add-offer-recipient

[image]

But in my app settings I have setup different urls for rediection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the prerequistics for AAC in that doc, it says "Contact your PayPal account manager to enable identity services."

If you don't have a PayPal account manager who's guiding you with this integration and enabling the necesary service for you, then you can't use this and should not be trying to follow this doc.

Comment: I am the one who did all configurations. Credentials are with me. I setup return URLs. Enabled payouts, Enabled Connect with PayPal to obtain Personal profile data

Comment: Please can you guide me about enabling identity services. This is sandbox environment

Comment: Doesn't matter, you're choosing to integrate something that requires a contact at PayPal to enable it on your account, be it a sandbox account or a live account.

Answer (score 0):

To me it worked after setting return URL as follows

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/conex/ac/add-offer-recipient

[image]